# How to Using uri get image in RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app in the Android studio. Click the button in the Fragment to open a dialog box and include a picture and a brief description. (Pictures are taken from your gallery.) Click OK to close the dialog box and include the image and description in the RecyclerView that exists in the Fragment. But this code that I've woven has a description, but it doesn's image. I wanted to hear a solution to this, so I asked you a question.

I'd appreciate your reply!

To briefly explain how my code works, when I receive an image from the dialog box, I send the path (/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/a.jpg) of the file as a toast message, and as soon as the dialog is closed, the imagepath and description are transferred to the String form, and the imagepath is converted from Fragment to uri and changed to Bitmap using it to apply to RecyclerView.

Below is my code.

**Fragment.java**

```
        btn_addlist = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_addlist);
        btn_addlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment_cus dialog = new DialogFragment_cus();
                dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
                dialog.setDialogResult(new DialogFragment_cus.OnMyDialogResult() {
//                    result : uri, result2 : dlg_edtName, result3 : dlg_edtSubtitle
                    @Override
                    public void finish(String result, String result2, String result3) {
                        imageUri = result;  RecyclerInputName = result2;
                        RecyclerInputSubtitle = result3;
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + imageUri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), uri);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        RecyclerItem_cus item = new RecyclerItem_cus(bitmap, RecyclerInputName, RecyclerInputSubtitle);
                        mArrayList.add(0, item);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "finish.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**DialogFragment.java**

```
        dlg_AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
        dlg_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment_cus fragment = new DialogFragment_cus();
                String input1 = dlg_edtName.getText().toString();
                String input2 = dlg_edtSubtitle.getText().toString();
                if(fragment != null) {
                    if(mDialogResult != null ) {
                        mDialogResult.finish(name_Str, input1, input2);
                    }
                }
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        dlg_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void setDialogResult(OnMyDialogResult dialogResult){
        mDialogResult = dialogResult;
    }

    public interface OnMyDialogResult{
        void finish(String result, String result2, String result3);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                name_Str = getImageNameToUri(data.getData());
                InputStream in = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
                dlg_ImageView.setImageBitmap(img);
                dlg_ImageView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.white);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "name_Str : "+name_Str , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public String getImageNameToUri(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        getActivity().startManagingCursor(cursor);
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
```

**RecyclerView_cusAdapter.java**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        final RecyclerItem_cus item = items.get(i);
        if (item != null) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(item.getImage())
                    .asBitmap()
                    .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                            myViewHolder.cus_img.setImageBitmap(resource);
                        }
                    });
            myViewHolder.cus_title.setText(item.getTitle());
            myViewHolder.cus_subtitle.setText(item.getSubTitle());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.items.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView cus_title;
        TextView cus_subtitle;
        ImageView cus_img;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cus_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cus_title);
            cus_subtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cus_subtitle);
            cus_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cus_img);
        }
    }
```

**RecyclerItem_cus.java**

```
public class RecyclerItem_cus {
    private Bitmap image;
    private String title;
    private String subTitle;

    public RecyclerItem_cus(Bitmap image, String title, String subTitle) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Glide with the File object directly :

```
Glide.with(mContext)
  .load(new File(item.getImage())) // Uri of the picture
  .into(myViewHolder.cus_img);
```

Comment: sorry. I still have not solved the problem. I tried this code, but I got an error.' .load(new File(item.getImage()))' item.getImage is Uri type?

Comment: You must create an Uri with the String from `item.getImage()`